# Cypress Test runner left pane closes after the salesforce application is open

Tags: automation, salesforce, cypress

Anyone having experience in automating Salesforce applications using Cypress?

I am able to open the application but the test runner left pane closes after the salesforce application is open and execution stops without any error report.

We can see in RED that the browser is handled by automation(Cypress) but there is no Test Runner left pane.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hey Hi, Did you find solution for the above issue?

Comment: HI, we did find the solution, 
1. Update cypress
2. update viewport - 1600 x 1000